# Navbar elements collapse to the row below after effects are added

Tags: html, css, positioning, navbar, element

My navbar looked fine: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/skycap/hvb3taav/9/)

```
<ul>
     <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   </ul>
```

After adding a hover effect, however, the elements seem to have gained an invisible extra px to the right like so: [link](http://prntscr.com/cbns4s)

```
<ul>
     <li><a class="active her-buzz-out" href=" #home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a class="her-buzz-out" href="#news">News</a></li>
     <li><a class="her-buzz-out" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
     <li><a class="her-buzz-out" href="#about">About</a></li>
   </ul>
```

they do not fit properly anymore and any attempt at moving them slightly to the right results in the farthest element to collapse to the row below... Using an absolute position would not be an option because I need it to be relative. Any ideas on how I could make the elements fit properly?

css is in the js fiddle page, unfortunately the effects library is on my computer so I am only able to describe the error...

Comment: well without knowing what is the CSS for the hover effect ( besides the change in background-color`) , we can't help you

Comment: you can set a container outside the `anchor` tag and give that a fixed width with overflow hidden!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give it a try!

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 265px;
    height: 2.45em;
    margin: 5em;
    border-radius: 500px;
    background-color: #4da6ff;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 1px;
    color: #4da6ff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8.5px 11px;
    margin-left:2px;
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 500px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  transition:all 400ms linear;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    padding: 14px 20px;
}

 .active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #4da6ff;
}
.out {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
}
.out {
    float: left;
    max-width: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
li a:hover .out{
      max-width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li><div class="out"><a class="active her-buzz-out" href=" #home">Home</a></div></li>
     <li><div class="out"><a class="her-buzz-out" href="#news">News</a></div></li>
     <li><div class="out"><a class="her-buzz-out" href="#contact">Contact</a></div></li>
     <li><div class="out"><a class="her-buzz-out" href="#about">About</a></div></li>
   </ul>
```